# gnome window top corners problem

Tags: gnome, 16.04

As you can see on the screenshot below, there is a problem on top of the windows. How can I fix this?

I installed ubuntu 16.04 then switched to gnome on login screen.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

By using theme that has good support for CSD windows. For example - Adwaita.

Comment: Or if you want beauty, Arc.